# How to generate an Escape key press in pure Typescript (w/o JQuery)

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I am trying to fire an Escape button press event in Angular unit tests.

```
    const event = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
    event.initUIEvent('keydown', true, true, window, 0);
    (<any>event).keyCode = 27;
    (<any>event).key = 'Escape';
    (<any>event).charCode = 27;

    document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This does not work at all (event is never caught by listeners that do proper checking like event.which == 27).

What is the correct way to create such an event?

I tried this one too, in vain

```
    const event = new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true});
    event.initEvent('keydown', true, true);
    (<any>event).keyCode = 27;
    (<any>event).key = 'Escape';
    (<any>event).charCode = 27;

    document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 5):

You only need to use a keyboard Event on document or on an element

```
     const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown",{
     'key': 'Escape'
     });
     document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can test it with HostListener

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
    let keyPressed = event.keyCode;
    if (keyPressed === 27) {
       console.log('Escape!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also omit checking `keyCode` using `@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])`